# Windows phone 8 Http client - Post data

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application. I need to send some data using the HTTP POST method but it doesn't work:

Here is my code:

```
 public async Task<bool> ConnexionPage()
    {
        bool _verif = false;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string data = "username=" + this.user + "&password=" + this.password + "&cmdweblogin=Enter";
        var postContent = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // send request asynchronously and continue when complete 
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://intranet.ifips.u-psud.fr/ii/index.php?id=571", postContent).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false); 

        // check that response was successful or throw exception response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        //Read the JSON response
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        _verif=true;
        return _verif;
    }
```

When I use a break point, I am blocked at line:  `var response = await client.PostAsyn`...

Comment: Did you cut instead of copy `var response = await client.PostAsyn`?

Comment: Yes I corrected it...

Comment: Well it's hard to say anything about it since this should just work. How long do you wait for it to finish? Can you inspect your network traffic to verify that you don't receive a response?

Comment: that's work when I use void instead of Task<bool> ... But if I use Task<bool> it's blocked after var response ) await client ....

Comment: Ok, After some research I found that call a http client with task.Result block the method.

Comment: You should always avoid calling `.Result` But this part isn't in your code so there's nothing we can say about it.